# Spring Security SAML + HTTPS to another page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I created a project with Spring Security SAML.

I need to write a code (same project), which connects with another server by HTTPS POST with SOAP:

```
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://www.somepage.com");
    post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "action");
    post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(soapXML, "text/xml", "UTF-8"));

    HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
    httpclient.executeMethod(post);

    String responseString = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

There is an error:

***SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null***

And every HTTPS requests are blocked by Spring Security SAML.

Configuration uses to keystore for SAML Idp Provider, but I need to send  request to another server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

// Initialization of the velocity engine
@Bean
public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
    return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
}

// XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
@Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
    return new StaticBasicParserPool();
}

@Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
    return new ParserPoolHolder();
}

// Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
@Bean
public MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager() {
    return new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
}

@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
}

// SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
// messages
@Bean
public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
    SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
    return samlAuthenticationProvider;
}

// Provider of default SAML Context
@Bean
public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() throws MetadataProviderException {
    SAMLContextProviderImpl sAMLContextProviderImpl = new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    MetadataCredentialResolver metadataCredentialResolver = new MetadataCredentialResolver(metadata(), keyManager());
    metadataCredentialResolver.setUseXmlMetadata(false);
    sAMLContextProviderImpl.setMetadataResolver(metadataCredentialResolver);
    return sAMLContextProviderImpl;
}

// Initialization of OpenSAML library
@Bean
public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
    return new SAMLBootstrap();
}

// Logger for SAML messages and events
@Bean
public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
    return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
}

// SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
}

// SAML 2.0 ECP profile
@Bean
public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
    return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
}

@Bean
public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
    return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
}

// Central storage of cryptographic keys
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
     DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
     Resource storeFile = loader
     .getResource("classpath:/saml/samlKeystore.jks");
     String storePass = "nalle123";
     Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
     passwords.put("apollo", "nalle123");
     String defaultKey = "apollo";
     return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}

// Setup TLS Socket Factory
@Bean
public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
    return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
    return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "default");
}

@Bean
public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
    return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
}

@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
    Object[] args = {"https", socketFactoryProtocol()};
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
    WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
    webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
    return webSSOProfileOptions;
}

// Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
// properties file
@Bean
public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
    SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
    samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
    return samlEntryPoint;
}

// Setup advanced info about metadata
@Bean
public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
    ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
    extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(false);
    extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(true);
    return extendedMetadata;
}

// IDP Discovery Service
@Bean
public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
    SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
    idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/saml/idpSelection");
    return idpDiscovery;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException {
    @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation"})
    //HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider 
    //  = new HTTPMetadataProvider("https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml", 5000);

    FilesystemMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new FilesystemMetadataProvider(new File("FederationMetadata.xml"));
    httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool()
    );
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate
            = new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}

// IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
// is here
// Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
@Bean
@Qualifier("metadata")
public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
    List<MetadataProvider> providers = new ArrayList<MetadataProvider>();
    providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
    return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
}

// Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
@Bean
public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
    MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
    metadataGenerator.setEntityId("com:vdenotaris:spring:sp");
    metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
    metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
    metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());
    return metadataGenerator;
}

// The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
// and presents SP metadata there
@Bean
public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
    return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
}

// Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
@Bean
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler
            = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
    return successRedirectHandler;
}

// Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
@Bean
public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler
            = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
    failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
    return failureHandler;
}

@Bean
public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
}

// Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
@Bean
public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
}

@Bean
public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
    return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
}

// Handler for successful logout
@Bean
public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
    SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
    return successLogoutHandler;
}

// Logout handler terminating local session
@Bean
public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler
            = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
    logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
    return logoutHandler;
}

// Filter processing incoming logout messages
// First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
// global logout
@Bean
public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
    return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
            logoutHandler());
}

// Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
// messages
@Bean
public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
    return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
            new LogoutHandler[]{logoutHandler()},
            new LogoutHandler[]{logoutHandler()});
}

// Bindings
private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
    final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile
            = new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
    artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
    return artifactResolutionProfile;
}

@Bean
public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
    return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
}

@Bean
public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
    return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
    return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
}

@Bean
public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
    return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
    return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
}

@Bean
public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
    return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
}

// Processor
@Bean
public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
    Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
    bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
    bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
    bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
    bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
    bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
    return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
}

/**
 * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using
 * SAML 2.0
 *
 * @return Filter chain proxy
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Bean
public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
    List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
            samlEntryPoint()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
            samlLogoutFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
            metadataDisplayFilter()));
    //chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
    //        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
            samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
    chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
            samlIDPDiscovery()));
    return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
}

/**
 * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring. It
 * represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from other classes
 * performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
 *
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

/**
 * Defines the web based security configuration.
 *
 * @param http It allows configuring web based security for specific http
 * requests.
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    http
            .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();

    http
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}

/**
 * Sets a custom authentication provider.
 *
 * @param auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
}

}
```

Logs:

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver - PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=test.test.pl,OU=test,O=test,L=test,ST=test,C=PL,2.5.4.5=#1320487a772f77645a513079554c4c346c3246716c76616f64694f6f34643149676a']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Trust of untrusted credential could not be established via PKIX validation
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Attempting PKIX validation of untrusted credential
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Beginning PKIX validation using trusted validation information
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator - Supplied trusted names are null or empty, skipping name evaluation
[ERROR] org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver - PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=test.test.pl,OU=test,O=test,L=test,ST=test,C=PL,2.5.4.5=#1320487a772f77645a513079554c4c346c3246716c76616f64694f6f34643149676a']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Trust of untrusted credential could not be established via PKIX validation
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Attempting PKIX validation of untrusted credential
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Beginning PKIX validation using trusted validation information
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator - Supplied trusted names are null or empty, skipping name evaluation
[ERROR] org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver - PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CN=test.test.pl,OU=test,O=test,L=test,ST=test,C=PL,2.5.4.5=#1320487a772f77645a513079554c4c346c3246716c76616f64694f6f34643149676a']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Trust of untrusted credential could not be established via PKIX validation
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Attempting PKIX validation of untrusted credential
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Beginning PKIX validation using trusted validation information
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509CredentialNameEvaluator - Supplied trusted names are null or empty, skipping name evaluation
[ERROR] org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver - PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='test,O=test,L=test,ST=test,C=PL,2.5.4.5=#1320487a772f77645a513079554c4c346c3246716c76616f64694f6f34643149676a']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[DEBUG] org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.PKIXX509CredentialTrustEngine - Trust of untrusted credential could not be established via PKIX validation
```

Comment: Are you using bean "org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer"?

Comment: Please attach your spring configuration and complete logs.

Answer (score 10):

You are using bean `TLSProtocolConfigurer` which changes trusted certificates and hostname verification of the HTTPS protocol in the HTTP Client. You can revert behaviour of the HTTP Client back to defaults by removing this bean. You will then need to make sure that certificates used by entities from which you load metadata (https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml) are trusted in your cacerts, or use an endpoints without https (http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml).

Alternatively, you can disable hostname verification by setting property `sslHostnameVerification` to `allowAll` on bean `TLSProtocolConfigurer`. You will also need to make sure that the HTTPS certificate of https://www.somepage.com (or its CA) is included in the samlKeystore.jks (see [Spring SAML manual](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-key-management-public-keys%20for%20instructions)).

You can find more details on the `TLSProtocolConfigurer` bean in the [Spring SAML manual, chapter HTTP-based metadata provider with SSL](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-https).

Comment: @Vladmir Schafer , How <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer"/> use with HTTP-based metadata provider