# SSL peer failed hostname validation in Spring SAML

Tags: spring-boot, spring-saml

I'm trying to configure my Spring Boot project to use SAML authentication against a third party IDP. I've already achieved to make the configuration from [vdenotaris](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) work with the SSOCircle provider and now I want to switch it to the other provider.

The SAML metadata endpoint is HTTPS enabled and I've already created a keystore with both the certificate given in metadata (which is used for signing and encryption) and the one provided by the HTTP endpoint (based in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28538799/1199132)). Then, I save them in a cert file ($CERTIFICATE_FILE) and I use this script to generate my keystore:

```
keytool -delete -alias third-party -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
keytool -import -alias third-party -file $CERTIFICATE_FILE -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE -storepass $KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -noprompt
keytool -genkeypair -alias mycompany -keypass mycompanypass -keystore $KEYSTORE_FILE
```

Then, when using this keystore to retrieve the SAML metadata, I get this error:

```
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error retrieving metadata from https://third.party.provider/metadata
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:267)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.doInitialization(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:236)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractMetadataProvider.initialize(AbstractMetadataProvider.java:407)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate.initialize(ExtendedMetadataDelegate.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.initializeProvider(MetadataManager.java:412)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager.refreshMetadata(MetadataManager.java:238)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager.refreshMetadata(CachingMetadataManager.java:86)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager$RefreshTask.run(MetadataManager.java:1040)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error retrieving metadata from https://third.party.provider/metadata
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:255)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

These ones are the relevant parts of my configuration based in the linked project by vdenotaris:

```java
// Setup TLS Socket Factory
@Bean
public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
    return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
}

@Bean
public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
    return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "allowAll");
}

@Bean
public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
    return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
}

@Bean
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
    Object[] args = { "https", socketFactoryProtocol() };
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}

// Central storage of cryptographic keys
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader.getResource("classpath:/saml/mySamlKeystore.jks");
    String storePass = "storepass";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwords.put("mycompany", "mycompanypass");
    String defaultKey = "mycompany";
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}
```

However, here I found some misconceptions. As far as I know, the `TLSProtocolConfigurer` creates a `TLSProtocolSocketFactory` itself, why is the sample project creating both beans then? According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-https) using `TLSProtocolConfigurer` should be enough, but how to create `socketFactoryProtocol()`?

I would be grateful to have some light in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't providing the password for the imported cert file:

```java
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader.getResource("classpath:/saml/mySamlKeystore.jks");
    String storePass = "storepass";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
    passwords.put("mycompany", "mycompanypass");
    passwords.put("third-party", "mycompanypass");
    String defaultKey = "mycompany";
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}
```

With this, the application can read the certs from the keystore and trust them, without the need of installing them in the JDK cacerts.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please help e in this. I have created new certificate and keystore, but again the error is same.
 SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null

Comment: @user3029929 please post a question with all the details.

Comment: I have the same problem (same error)which is mentioned in the post.. 

@Xtreme Biker: as you  mentioned in your answer that you just added password for the certificate and it worked for you. I n my case i created my new certificate without password, and i am getting same error which is mentioned in this question . May be I am creating certificates in worng way. Can you please let me know the right way..

Answer (score 7):

Here is my JKS key-manager bean configuration.

```
@Bean
public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "default");
}

@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
Resource storeFile = loader.getResource("classpath:/saml/samlKeystore.jks");
String storePass = keyStorePwd;
Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
passwords.put(keyStoreAlias, keyStorePwd);
String defaultKey = keyStoreAlias;
return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);

}
```

### Solution:

Looks like the IDP has changed their Public certificate which is not available in our local keystore (samlKeystore.jks). I manually downloaded their public certificate using OpenSSL command and imported the same using keytool utility.

#### Get the public certificate using OpenSSL command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect iam-sso.google.net:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >mycertfile.pem
```

#### Import it into the Keystore:

```
keytool -import -alias "new-public-cert" -keystore /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/saml/samlKeystore.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
        throws MetadataProviderException {
    String idpSSOCircleMetadataURL = "https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml";
    HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
            this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpSSOCircleMetadataURL);
    httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
    ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = 
            new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);
    extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
    backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
    return extendedMetadataDelegate;
}
```

**extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(false);**

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `TLSProtocolConfigurer` bean and set metadata trust check to `false`